# Keras Deep learning R tensorflow iris prediction classes

Tags: r, file, csv, keras, predict

I would like to predict classes from file which store iris values.
Model accuracy seems good with a value:

```
perf = model %>% evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(perf)
## $loss
## [1] 0.3843208
## 
## $acc
## [1] 1
```

My issue, as soon as I want to predict classes;

```
#load new data from file for prediction
library(readr)
Variants <- read.table(here::here("data","Species_to_predict.csv"), sep=";", header=T, dec=".", fill=TRUE)
# Predicted Class
yhat_keras_class_vec <- predict_classes(object = model, x = as.matrix(Variants)) 
yhat_keras_class_vec
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
[30] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I have the same output value. Do you know what I am doing wrong or do you know if there is any bug with keras predict.classes?

**Here my implementation:**

```
library("keras")
library("tidyverse")
nn_dat = iris %>% as_tibble %>%
  mutate(sepal_l_feat = scale(Sepal.Length),
         sepal_w_feat = scale(Sepal.Width),
         petal_l_feat = scale(Petal.Length),
         petal_w_feat = scale(Petal.Width),          
         class_num    = as.numeric(Species) - 1, # factor, so = 0, 1, 2
         class_label  = Species) %>%
  select(contains("feat"), class_num, class_label)
nn_dat %>% head(3)
test_f = 0.20
nn_dat = nn_dat %>%
  mutate(partition = sample(c('train','test'), nrow(.), replace = TRUE, prob = c(1 - test_f, test_f)))
x_train = nn_dat %>% filter(partition == 'train') %>% select(contains("feat")) %>% as.matrix
y_train = nn_dat %>% filter(partition == 'train') %>% pull(class_num) %>% to_categorical(3)
x_test  = nn_dat %>% filter(partition == 'test')  %>% select(contains("feat")) %>% as.matrix
y_test  = nn_dat %>% filter(partition == 'test')  %>% pull(class_num) %>% to_categorical(3)

model = keras_model_sequential()
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 4, activation = 'relu', input_shape = 4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax')
model %>% summary

model %>% compile(
  loss      = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics   = c('accuracy')
)
history = model %>% fit(
  x = x_train, y = y_train,
  epochs           = 200,
  batch_size       = 20,
  validation_split = 0
)
perf = model %>% evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(perf)
plot_dat = nn_dat %>% filter(partition == 'test') %>%
  mutate(class_num = factor(class_num),
         y_pred    = factor(predict_classes(model, x_test)),
         Correct   = factor(ifelse(class_num == y_pred, "Yes", "No")))
plot_dat %>% select(-contains("feat")) %>% head(3)

#load new data from file for prediction
library(readr)
Variants <- read.table(here::here("data","Species_to_predict.csv"), sep=";", header=T, dec=".", fill=TRUE)
# Predicted Class
yhat_keras_class_vec <- predict_classes(object = model, x = as.matrix(Variants)) 
yhat_keras_class_vec
```

Comment: What is the data in `species_to_predict.csv`? Do you know the true classes? It seems likely that the model is working fine but all of the data in the CSV belongs to class 2.

Comment: I know true classes into data in species_to_predict.csv, for example: row1:versicolor; row2:virginica; row3:virginica; row4:virginica; row5 :virginica

Comment: Is the data scaled? You scaled all of your predictors when training the model. And if it is scaled, is it scaled the same way (i.e. using the mean and sd from `iris` and not the new data)?

Comment: good remark, no I have scaled my data before predicting. i will do it to know if there is any difference. Keep you posted.

Comment: I did: Variants <- scale(Variants). The output sounds a lil bit better. How do you do sd on Variants?

Comment: You just use `scale`, but you need to change the default arguments so that you are applying the same transformation as when the model was trained. For your example you would do `scale(Variants, attr(scale(iris[1:4]), "scaled:center"), attr(scale(iris[1:4]), "scaled:scale"))`.

Comment: Thanks DiceboyT, it works now ;-)